# php Error occurred: 404 - not found

Tags: php, http-status-code-404

I migrated my webfiles and database to a new host/new servers.
The home page works fine, but when I click ANY links I get this error:

Error occurred: 404 - not found
underneath a line it says:
Apache Server at: s210939.instanturl.net    (the "instanturl.net" url my test site).

For example - this message comes when I go to:  http://s210939.instanturl.net/tls-t3.com/services/tls-t3-c-level-advisory

My site uses PHP and my files are not indexed as "tls-t3.com" --> "services" --> "tls-t3-c-level-advisory".

Why do I get this 404 error message with all my links and how can I resolve this?

Here is my [directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lw2NJ.jpg).

Comment: What does your directory structure look like?

Comment: there is no code to support the php and mysql tags.

Comment: @Fred-ii-   Thanks.  Why does the code work fine on my old servers/old host; but now it doesn't work on the new host?  I checked and the new servers support mysql and my version of php.  I would think if the coding works perfectly fine on my old host, it should work fine with the new host.

Comment: My guess is misconfiguration of `URL Rewriting`.